# Get the response from WKWebView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, networking, swiftui, spotify

I am new in networking, and trying to build and app that retrieves users top Spotify tracks using SwiftUI. Currently I'm stuck trying to implement authorization to your Spotify account. Here is my View with authorization:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct AuthView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = WKWebView
    
    let webView: WKWebView
    var url: String = "https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri=https://pie-test-login/callback&response_type=token"
    
    init() {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: url)!)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        webView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct AuthView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AuthView()
    }
}
```

It allows user to login, but I don't understand how to get the response with the authorization code after the authorization. Will appreciate any help/comments!

Comment: https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/ios-wkwebview-communication-using-javascript-and-swift-ee077e0127eb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer:

```
struct AuthView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = AuthViewController
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var accessToken: String?
    
    var url: String = "https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri= REDIRECT_STRING&response_type=code"
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AuthViewController {
        let viewController = AuthViewController(isPresented: $isPresented, accessToken: $accessToken)
        viewController.url = url
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AuthViewController, context: Context) {
    }
    
}

class AuthViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    private var webView: WKWebView!
    var url: String = ""
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var accessToken: String?
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, accessToken: Binding<String?>) {
            _isPresented = isPresented
            _accessToken = accessToken
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }
        
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupWebView()
        loadWebView()
    }
    
    private func setupWebView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    private func loadWebView() {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }
        
        let urlString = url.absoluteString
        let api = API()
        
        // Check if the URL contains your redirect URI
        if urlString.contains(REDIRECT_STRING) {
            // Extract the authorization code from the URL
   
            }
      
    } 
    
}
```

We need to create delegate, that will look for updates in url, and when it's updated and it contains the redirect url, we do operations